# applying gradient in css from photoshop

Tags: css

i am working on section which has a gradient feature! this is what it looks like from photoshop!
[image]

now this is what i have done so far what i did  is i took opened the tools and took the starting colors and ending colors from gradient overlay in Photoshop but they are not just same moreover i saw some scale attributes in Photoshop which i tried searching for in html but couldn't find any! anyhow here's my current code

```
<div class="aboutus-section2">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">



            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jpjyhjwz/)

Comment: By simply copy the colors from the image it works https://jsfiddle.net/jpjyhjwz/2/ ... so what is the actual question?

Comment: wow that was i looking for! can just please tell me how you got the colors from image?

Comment: and you can write it as an answer so i can mark it

Comment: Thanks ...search for _photoshop color picker_ and you'll find how to get the colors. Also, as this is kind of off-topic for SO (more a Photoshop how-to issue) a posted answer will not be very useful for future users.